# what is the best solution socket or net remoting or wcf in mini dbms

Tags: wcf, sockets, remoting

I have a project

This project same [Sedna](http://www.sedna.org/)

my project is data base management system but stor data in xml files

I need a way to connect to server but I 'm confused to use socket or dot net remoting or wcf .

what is the best solution for server

socket or dot net remoting or  wcf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net remoting is legacy technology. My opinion that WCF would be good. It's advice from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) site.